# spring-data-mongo repository geoIntersects

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to create a repository based on PagingAndSortingRepository, including a method to look for which neighbourhood contains a location, and I was thinking something like:

```
List<Neighbourhood> findByLocationIntersects(Point point);
```

Neighbourhood includes the property:

```
private GeoJsonPolygon location;
```

In terms of a mongo query it would be something like:

```
db.neighbourhoods.find({ location: { $geoIntersects: { $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -34.610268, -58.363397 ] } } } })
```

Unfortunately this is failing, am I losing something or this is not implemente yet in spring-data-mongodb?

Comment: Not everything translates to the "named method helpers" in MongoRespository classes. You really should be using the full instance methods API for anything beyond very basic CRUD.

Comment: Hey Neil, thanks for the reply.
I took and approach similar to what you suggest, creating a new interface with the method, and implementing it with the mongoTemplate...